# Multi select List column loses its values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, splistitem

I have a text column with some validation

This column is bound to a list/content type.

One of the other columns in the list is a multi select lookup column. The values for the multi select column are sourced from another list.

Finally a third column is set to validate for unique entries per row

All columns are set up to be required

If the user enters a duplicate value in the unique column  the values in the multi select column disappear. Basically any validation that requires postback clears the multi select column

Any tips would be much appreciated

Comment: Is there any custom javascript code on your form?

Comment: Not at all. This is using OOTB view/page on an OOTB column with a formula to validate the email address

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the formula here in your question? That maybe helpful

Comment: Sure Ganesh. The validation is as follows                                          <Validation Message="Enter a valid email address">=OR(ISBLANK([Authors Email Address]), AND(ISERROR(FIND(" ",[Authors Email Address],1)),
IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",[Authors Email Address],2)),FALSE,
AND(ISERROR(FIND("@",[Authors Email Address],FIND("@",[Authors Email Address],2)+1)),
IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",[Authors Email Address],FIND("@",[Authors Email Address],2)+2)),
FALSE,FIND(".",[Authors Email Address],FIND("@",[Authors Email Address],2)+2)&lt;LEN([Authors Email Address]))))))</Validation>

Comment: Where are you add the validation?

Comment: In column validation

Comment: Ok so this happens if the validation requires postback